# Cannot find module `dist/bin/x.js` when trying to use the command that comes with the package after npm global install

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm, npm-install

You did `npm install -g aVeryCoolPackage` and when you want to use `aVeryCoolPackage`'s command in your shell you get an error like this:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aVeryCoolPackage/dist/bin/cli.js'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
  at loadAVeryCoolPackage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aVeryCoolPackage/bin/aVeryCoolPackage.js:30:3)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aVeryCoolPackage/bin/aVeryCoolPackage.js:44:5
  at LOOP (fs.js:1758:14)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

After you cd into `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/thePackage` to your surprise you see that the folder `dist` does not exist at all. This is strange. You tried `npm uninstall -g aVeryCoolPackage` and then `npm install -g aVeryCoolPackage` again but you run into the same problem when trying to use its command. Everyone else on github is not running into this problem. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I had cloned the repo from github. And I did `npm install -g aVeryCoolPackage` at the same directory as where the repo is, so it actually installed my local copy of it where it has `.gitignore` the `dist` folder. As a result I didn't have `dist` in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aVeryCoolPackage/` and it threw the Cannot find module error every time it tried to `require` files in it.

Fun fact: You would have no idea how the error arises if you `npm uninstall -g aVeryCoolPackage` and `npm install -g aVeryCoolPackage` at a different directory where the clone of the repo is not there and getting it fixed as a result. It would become one of those mysteries in node development where sometimes you get strange errors and then you stop seeing them.